# Extract line with exact number of strings

Tags: text-extraction

I would like to extract lines from a text file which contain the exact number of characters on it.  I tried colrm but it does not met my wanted result and exclude non alphanumeric symbols. Can anyone do this using using sed? I am new to sed, i am still reading though... thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Is there a language preference?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a test file to run this against, I called the file "test":

```
1
11
123
1234
12345
55555
123456
666666
```

## grep

To only print lines with 5 characters use the following

```
cat test | grep '^.\{5\}$'
```

Result:

```
12345
55555
```

On the command line you need to escape the curly brackets,

## sed

```
cat test | sed '/^.\{5\}$/!d'
```

In sed this uses the same regex as above, but the `/!d` tells sed NOT to delete the lines that match this. The result will be the same two lines as above.

## awk

The curly braces can cause issues in some versions of awk, and may require special flags not available. Here is one basic way of doing it with awk

```
cat test |  awk '{ if (length($0) == 5 ) print $0}'
```

Comment: ahhhh... that hits the spot... thanks Eric... it works even though some symbols and special characters are included, ill keep on reading the tutorial how to exclude those symbols and spcial chars.. thanks again

Comment: what characters do you want to exclude? you can use a special letter class instead of the `.` modified, maybe something like `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. If you edit your question with some sample lines and the one which should be excluded we can help. It sounds like your source file may have control characters in it.

Comment: oh sorry for that.. anyway i have found and managed too search for the task i wanted.. sed 's/^> //' inputfile but your suggestion to replace . with [a-zA-Z0-9] is much easier to understand...

Answer (score 0):

`grep '^.{25}$'` would return only lines with exactly 25 characters, I think.

Explanation:

```
^     Start at beginning of string
.{25} match exactly 25 of any character
$     Up to the end of the string`
```

Comment: This is a lot easier in grep then sed. Sed is better for inline edits, when you just want to get out matching lines, grep is a bit easier to use.

Comment: @EricG I suspect  your comment was being written just as I was editing the answer since I recognized the same problem after I hit "submit". Our thoughts crossed in cyberspace... Missed the escaped braces though.